# Best practices for maintaining Ubuntu packages across versions?

Tags: build, git-buildpackage

I have a bunch of packages in my [PPA](https://launchpad.net/~grumbel/+archive/ppa) and a reasonable knowledge on how to build Debian/Ubuntu packages, so far so good. My issue is that I don't really have an idea how to properly maintain them for different versions of Ubuntu and how to handle Ubuntu upgrades. Right now I am doing all of these things manually, which for most part simply means updating the version number in `debian/changelog` and reuploading them, which sounds easy enough, however when having to do that for a dozen packages, across numerous versions of Ubuntu, things can get a little tiresome and error prone.

When there are small changes needed to be done to the `debian/control` files, `debian/rules` or the source things get of course even more complicated. While I can maintain those changes in `git-buildpackage` fine, getting constant merge conflicts in the `debian/control` file, due to backports having different version number then the current package, kind of throws me of the rails and makes things even more complicated.

So essentially: What are some best practices for building and maintaining Ubuntu packages, so that it's easy to make them available across multiple version of Ubuntu?

Answer (score 1):

Good question , as am learning packages myself and want to maintain a package for a good software project .. have you looked at the following page :

https://wiki.ubuntu.com/PackagingGuide/Complete

Comment: I don't feel this is an answer. It should rather be a comment.